# How to do Xpath's result becomes my output result?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I am studying XML and XSLT with Java. I already created some APPs long time ago with ASP 3 and Javascript using these techniques. Now I am trying to remember some techniques with Xpath and understand how to make this in Java.

I used to make in the past a Xpath to get some elements from the XML and transform it in my HTML output. I have been trying to make the same in java, but I think I am a bit lost.

I already looked for in others posts here, but usually the samples are just getting the Node's values and showing in a loop. I would like to get a snippet of XML and transform this in a output HTML.

I have this simple sample bellow which works fine.

```
  Source source = new StreamSource("catalog.xml");
  Source xsl = new StreamSource("catalog.xsl");
  //Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);
  Result result = new StreamResult("output.html");

  TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  transformer.transform(source, result);
```

I am using **javax.xml.**. I saw several examples using **javax.xml.xpath.**. And I tested some examples of Xpath as well.

But so far I did not realize how to get a snippet code from the XML and transform this in my output.html.

My XML:

```
<catalog>
    <cd active="1">
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd active="1">
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd active="0">
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>

</catalog>
```

For example, if I want to transform just this Xpath bellow in my output.html:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//catalog/cd[active='0']");
```

How to do this in my Java?

- *I know I could do this in my XSL with a simple Xpath, but it's just an example.*

If I was not clear, let me know.

Comment: Just to make shure that I understand you correct. You are trying to transform just a portion of the Source.xml file to the target, by selecting the portion by a XPath in Java, without changing the source xml, or the xsl?

Comment: Your xpath is missing a "@" on the attribute : //catalog/cd[@active='0']

Comment: @treeno Yes. That's the idea.

Comment: @StevenD.Majewski Thanks for the advice. I am trying your code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transformer.transform takes a javax.xml.transform.Source which can also be a DOMSource.

javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource has a constructor that takes a node.

When you evaluate you xpath expression, ask for a NODE as a return value. ( text is the default ) and call DOMsource on that as your source.

In Jython, for example, it would be something like:

```
from javax.xml.transform.stream import StreamSource, StreamResult
from javax.xml.transform import *
from javax.xml.xpath import *
from org.xml.sax import InputSource
from javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants import *
from javax.xml.transform.dom import DOMSource

xsl=StreamSource('catalog.xsl')
# source = StreamSource( 'catalog.xml' )
result = StreamResult( 'output.html' )

xfact=XPathFactory.newInstance()
xpath=xfact.newXPath()
expr = xpath.compile("//catalog/cd[@active='0']")
x=expr.evaluate( InputSource( 'catalog.xml' ), NODE )

factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl)

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes")
transformer.transform( DOMSource(x), result)
```

No error checking in this version:
You might want to ask for a NODESET instead and check that you got one and only one return value.

I fixed your xpath expression as well. You were missing the '@' on the attribute.

Comment: After adapting my code, I am getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException in my catalog.xml and it's strange because the file continues in the same place and before worked fine.

Comment: Please forget this exception it was my mistake. Now everything seems ok. I am just testing the XPath.